# Creating a customized toolbar to control autoCAD with C#

Tags: c#, .net, autocad, autocad-plugin

I need to create an application that has some autoCAD functions like enter, esc, offset, etc. I have this example to work on:

[GUI example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YK98A.jpg)

So basically the toolbar stays always on top of every window then, when I open autoCAD and press any button, autoCAD recognize the button pressed and run the specific function. I thought about creating an application to do keyboard commands like if I have an enter button, it's like pressing enter on the keyboard. Seems legit in theory, but the problem is that autocad never do those functions because I'm still on the application window.

The issue is that I have no idea on where to start. I am researching something with user32.dll and setForegroundWindow(), but I am super lost.

Any idea on where or what to study would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U have to Type CUI in the Command Line to do this
CUI : Stands for Customer User Interface
This will open up a Window, Here
Near to the Bottom Left
1. You have to Right Click on any Command & Press New Coammand
2. On the Right Side on the New Command, The Properties related to the Command Opens.
3. There is a TAB Where MACRO is mentioned with "^C^C" Written, all you have to do is Edit that with your Customization.
4. Make a New Logo
5. Make a New Toolbar.
6. Drag & Drop This Command into that
7. Thats it, Your New Command Toolbar will appear under the Toolbar Section in Autocad.

Thanks